# Installing azure-cli in bash on windows throws errors: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, bash, azure-cli

I installed Azure-cli using npm. When I run the azure command I get the following error: `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (therefore Ubuntu) installs node as `nodejs` as opposed to `node`.

Azure CLI is programmed to use `node`.

Need to create an alias so `node` points to `nodejs`. You do so with the following comman:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`